# Cosmic acceleration in the LCDM model

Tags: cosmology, acceleration

As the LCDM universe has entered the dark-energy deSitter exponential phase, how is it plausible that the acceleration of the cosmic expansion (e.g. =cH0 at the distance of the Hubble sphere) is so very low?

Comment: Low compared with *what*? You can have exponential expansion with *any* doubling time.

Comment: Do you intend that "Hubble sphere" means the sphere with Earth at its center which is known as the "Observable universe"? Please take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe .